# Admin Routing in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, admin, cakephp-2.3

Im trying to put my app under /admin on cakephp. And i am trying to configure the admin routing. What im trying to achive is this:

Lets say the page is **www.example.com**  so when the user type **www.example.com/admin** i want him/her to be redirected to the admin_dashboard.ctp (if it is logged in, otherwise redirect to log-in page). But now the problem is when i type **www.example.com/admin** it shows an error like:

Action PagesController::admin_index() could not be found

but if i do:

`www.example.com/admin/users/dashboard` it is redirected properly.

How can i achieve that? so just by typing /admin to redirect to dashboard??

and another thing is it possible to remove `/users/` from url and just display admin/dashboard?

On core.php file i have added the following line:

```
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin'));
```

And on the routes.php i have these lines :

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard', 'dashboard'));

Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));

/* I added this line for admin routing */
        Router::connect('/admin', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => true));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In routes.php write

```
 Router::connect('/admin', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard', 'admin' => true));
```

instead of

```
 Router::connect('/admin', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'index', 'admin' => true));
```

This redirect you to admin_dashboard when you type www.example.com/admin.

Comment: I resolved my problem. But thanx for your answer @Rajeev anyway.
And yeah i did the same thing as you said therefor your answer is correct, so i'm gonna upvote ;) Thanx again.

Answer (score 0):

Routing prefixes are added to the action name when looking for its corresponding method in the Controller.

In the Pages Controller rename your index() method into admin_index() as suggested by the error you are getting.